# How can I get my userID from my user recordset wihtout using a $_GET and URL variables

Tags: php, sql, get

So, I am trying to figure a way to update my user table, while using WHERE userID = (value from user table, another SQL query) without using URL variables or $_GET.

```
$query_recordUser = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE userID = 1"; //part of my sql query
$updateTheTable = sprintf("UPDATE user SET userSomeCol = 0 WHERE userID=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_GET['userID'], "int"));
```

I am not sure how to go about this. Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to use a result from a query (without resorting to URL variables) to my update code. I somehow need to get the userID from my sql query to the update query, if that makes any sense. As of right now, I can only seem to get it to target all the userID's, or use a GET/URL variable.

Comment: Ok so using a query result for another query. Have you tried: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {}?

Comment: Yes. it returns "Undefined index: userID", at least while trying  GetSQLValueString($row_recordUser['userID'], "int")); in the update part

Comment: URL variables are the same as $_GET variables. Use $_POST or $_SESSION or maybe even $_COOKIE

Comment: Honestly, that's probably what I'll end up doing. Ty for responses. It really isn't pertinent that I find an answer to this. Was just wondering if there was an easy fix to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

To use a result from a query in another query, you can do this:

```
$sql_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE userID = 1");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
$sql_result2 = $mysqli->query("delete * FROM `user` WHERE ... = $row['columnname']"); //this is just an example
}
```

This should work. Let me know if it didn't